# Gradle build no complete

Tags: spring, gradle, intellij-idea, build

I create the project in spring, but I have a problem with build gradle. I'm using IntelliJ and i have instal JDK Java 10 and Gradle 4.7. How to fix this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXiFz.jpg)

Comment: You want help with gradle, but you don't even post your gradle? How are we going to help you?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you have

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

in your build.gradle and re-import the project (Gradle project tool window) in IDE.